# Use pykalman to predict further steps on dynamic objects

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, prediction, kalman-filter, pykalman

I'm trying to use the Kalman Filter to predict the next object position. My data is composed of latitude and longitude each 1s, so, I also can get the velocity.

The below code shows a trying of pykalman package to predict further positions. I just modified the measurement values by adding the first three lat/lon values. Are the transition_matrices and observation_matrices right? I don't know how should I set them up.

```
#!pip install pykalman
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = [[1, 1], [0, 1]], observation_matrices = [[0.1, 0.5], [-0.3, 0.0]])
measurements = np.asarray([[41.4043467,  2.1765616], [41.4043839,  2.1766097], [41.4044208,  2.1766576]])  # 3 observations
kf = kf.em(measurements, n_iter=5)
(filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = kf.filter(measurements)
(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = kf.smooth(measurements)
```

The result is the following, far away from a right output.

```
smoothed_state_means
array([[-1.65091776, 23.94730577],
       [23.15197525, 21.2257123 ],
       [43.96359962, 21.9785667 ]])
```

How can I fix this? What I'm missing?

The path has this shape when using lat/long

[image]

UPDATED

I've tried these conversion ways:

1.

```
R = 6378388.0 # m
rlat1_225 = math.radians(lat_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude'].values[i-1]/10000000)
rlon1_225 = math.radians(lon_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_longitude'].values[i-1]/10000000)
       
dx = R * math.cos(rlat1_225) * math.cos(rlon1_225)
dy = R * math.cos(rlat1_225) * math.sin(rlon1_225)
pos_x = abs(dx*1000)
pos_y= abs(dy*1000)
```

[image]

2.

```
altitude=0
arc= 2.0*np.pi*(R+altitude)/360.0 #
latitude=lat_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude']/10000000
longitude=lon_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_longitude']/10000000
dx = arc * np.cos(latitude*np.pi/180.0) * np.hstack((0.0, np.diff(longitude))) # in m
dy = arc * np.hstack((0.0, np.diff(latitude))) # in m
```

[image]

The first approach seems the correct shape, however, after applying EKF (I've followed the explanation from Michel Van Biezen where the tracking plane I could make it work in python).

So, I follow the first way using EKF the prediction is:

[image]

However, when I overlap the predicted and the original path, I get this plot

[image]

Then, doing the prediction using the second approach, the result is

[image]

Seems the first approach the correct one, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the lat / long position in a local cartesian coordiante system. You could set the origin within the first received location. Regarding this system you can then estimate the relative position and velocity.

Transition matrix depends on your chosen states, for e.g. 2 states, x-position and v-velocity in that axis you would have: x_k+1 = x_k + v_k * dT and v_k+1 = v_k. Which is:

```
transition_matrices = [[1, dT], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: First make sure your input is correct. Doesnt look correct having values with the order of 1e8