# Use pykalman to predict gps gap values

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, prediction, kalman-filter, pykalman

Given [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10pZqjvOLEihFzO2uJIAfc8zxKysWlOI9/view?usp=sharing) GPS dataset (`sample.csv`) from Beijing, I am trying to apply [pyKalman](https://pykalman.github.io/) so as to fill the gaps on the GPS series. The code I am using is taken from [here](https://github.com/gaumarjos/TrackAnalyser/blob/master/bombo.py):

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():

    method = 1
    coords = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
    # coords.index = pd.to_datetime(coords.index)
    coords['time'] = pd.to_datetime(coords['time'])
    coords = coords.sort_values(by="time").reset_index(drop=True)
    # coords = coords[coords['time'].ne(coords['time'].shift())]
    coords.set_index('time', inplace=True, drop=True)
    coords = coords[~coords.index.duplicated()]

    coords['idx'] = range(0, len(coords))

    if method == 1:

        print(coords.head())
        coords.index = np.round(coords.index.astype(np.int64), -9).astype('datetime64[ns]')

        coords = coords.resample('1S').asfreq()

        measurements = np.ma.masked_invalid(coords[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']].values)

    else:
        import datetime
        METHOD_MAX_GAP = 20  # seconds
        """
        Method 2: fill the gaps between points close to each other's with NaNs and leave the big holes alone.
        The resulting sampling time is not constant
        """
        for i in range(0, len(coords) - 1):
            gap = coords.index[i + 1] - coords.index[i]
            if datetime.timedelta(seconds=1) < gap <= datetime.timedelta(seconds=METHOD_MAX_GAP):
                gap_idx = pd.date_range(start=coords.index[i] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1),
                                        end=coords.index[i + 1] - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1),
                                        freq='1S')
                gap_coords = pd.DataFrame(coords, index=gap_idx)
                coords = coords.append(gap_coords)
                # print("Added {} points in between {} and {}"
                # .format(len(gap_idx), coords.index[i], coords.index[i + 1]))
        # Sort all points
        coords = coords.sort_index()
        # Fill the time_sec column
        coords['time_sec'] = np.nan
        for i in range(0, len(coords)):
            coords['time_sec'].values[i] = (coords.index[i] - datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).total_seconds()
        coords['time_sec'] = coords['time_sec'] - coords['time_sec'][0]
        # Create the "measurement" array and mask NaNs
        measurements = coords[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']].values
        measurements = np.ma.masked_invalid(measurements)

    # Covariances: Position = 0.0001deg = 11.1m, Altitude = 30m
    cov = {'coordinates': 1.,
           'elevation': 30.,
           'horizontal_velocity': 1e-3,
           'elevation_velocity': 1e-3,
           'horizontal_acceleration': 1e-6 * 1000,
           'elevation_acceleration': 1e-6 * 1000}
    if method == 1:
        transition_matrices = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                                        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                                        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                                        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
    else:
        # The samples are randomly spaced in time, so dt varies with time and a
        # time dependent transition matrix is necessary
        timesteps = np.asarray(coords['time_sec'][1:]) - np.asarray(coords['time_sec'][0:-1])
        transition_matrices = np.zeros(shape=(len(timesteps), 6, 6))
        for i in range(len(timesteps)):
            transition_matrices[i] = np.array([[1., 0., 0., timesteps[i], 0., 0.],
                                               [0., 1., 0., 0., timesteps[i], 0.],
                                               [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., timesteps[i]],
                                               [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
                                               [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
                                               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
    observation_matrices = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

    # observation_covariance = np.diag([1e-4, 1e-4, 100]) ** 2
    observation_covariance = np.diag([cov['coordinates'], cov['coordinates'], cov['elevation']]) ** 2

    initial_state_mean = np.hstack([measurements[0, :], 3 * [0.]])
    # works initial_state_covariance = np.diag([1e-3, 1e-3, 100, 1e-4, 1e-4, 1e-4])**2
    # initial_state_covariance = np.diag([1e-4, 1e-4, 50, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6]) ** 2
    initial_state_covariance = np.diag([cov['coordinates'], cov['coordinates'], cov['elevation'],
                                        cov['horizontal_velocity'], cov['horizontal_velocity'],
                                        cov['elevation_velocity']]) ** 2

    kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices=transition_matrices,
                      observation_matrices=observation_matrices,
                      observation_covariance=observation_covariance,
                      initial_state_mean=initial_state_mean,
                      initial_state_covariance=initial_state_covariance,
                      # em_vars=['transition_matrices',
                      #          'observation_matrices',
                      #          'transition_offsets',
                      #          'observation_offsets',
                      #          'transition_covariance',
                      #          'observation_covariance',
                      #          'initial_state_mean',
                      #          'initial_state_covariance'
                      #          ]
                      )

    kf = kf.em(measurements, n_iter=5)
    state_means, state_vars = kf.smooth(measurements)
    # Increase observation co-variance
    kf.observation_covariance = kf.observation_covariance * 10

    filled_coords = state_means[coords['idx'].isnull(), :3]
    orig_coords = coords[~coords['idx'].isnull()].set_index('idx')

    plt.plot(orig_coords['lon'], orig_coords['lat'], 'r.', markersize=2, label='original')
    plt.plot(filled_coords[:, 0], filled_coords[:, 1], 'go', markersize=2, label='filled')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of `method 1` is

[image]

While the output of `method 2` is [image]. Could you please explain why `method 1` returns this strange result? In addition, in `method 2`, the upper right part of the GPS series is not filled. Is that because of wrong initialization?

<sup>Here I attach some similar posts [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432475/use-pykalman-to-predict-further-steps-on-dynamic-objects) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947643/kalman-filter-prediction-in-case-of-missing-measurement-and-only-positions-are-k) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288319/kalman-filter-to-predict-previous-step-from-future) [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377626/how-to-use-kalman-filter-in-python-for-location-data/43568887#43568887), [[5]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420541/giving-uncertainties-to-interpolated-values-in-time-series-application-to-mass).</sup>

Comment: To maximise chances of people offering answers would recommend you provide an [MCVE] - you've included a link to the data which is great - but your code doesn't start from loading the data. Also I'd recommend working on one 'axis' at a time at least initially - looking at your dynamics I don't think there's any coupling between the lat/lon/alt axes anyway.

Comment: @kabdulla I have added a reproducible example. What do you mean by " looking at your dynamics I don't think there's any coupling between the lat/lon/alt axes anyway." ?